# LeetCode#494 target sum (dart is slower than python)

Tags: performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, comparative-review, dart

I'm trying to solve a LeetCode problem [target-sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/), in two languages: Python & Dart. The difference of time taken is shocking for me"

- Python took ~70ms while Dart took ~900ms !! Why does Dart take so long? [screenshot](https://postimg.cc/rdrzLXD1)
- What should I do to improve Dart performance?

Solution in two different languages are as follows (same approach):

Python:

```py
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        dp = {}
        
        def calculate(i, total):
            if(i == len(nums)):
                return 1 if (total == target) else 0
            
            if((i, total) in dp):
                return dp[(i, total)]
            
            dp[(i, total)]  = calculate(i+1, total + nums[i]) + calculate(i+1, total - nums[i])
            
            return dp[(i, total)]
        
        return calculate(0, 0)
```

Dart

```dart
class Solution {
  int findTargetSumWays(List<int> nums, int target) {
    Map<MapEntry<int, int>, int> dp = {};
    int calculate(int i, int sum) {
      if (i == nums.length) {
        return sum == target ? 1 : 0;
      }

      final pair = MapEntry(i, sum);
      return dp[pair] ??
          (dp[pair] = calculate(i + 1, sum + nums[i]) +
              calculate(i + 1, sum - nums[i]));
    }

    return calculate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Is Dart map causing this delay? If so what operations should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please [edit] to add a short summary of the problem statement?  You can keep the link as a reference, but your question does need to be complete even if the linked material isn't accessible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use *hashable* types as hashtable keys

An important requirement of hashtables is that they keys must be hashable:

- has a `.hashCode` implementation that returns the same value for two objects that are equal
- has a `.equals` implementation that returns true for two objects that are equal

Looking at the documentation of [`MapEntry`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/MapEntry-class.html),
it looks like it inherits the `hashCode` and `equals` implementations from `Object`,
which means it's not hashable.

The problem is that these objects are not equal:

```
MapEntry x = MapEntry(a, b);
MapEntry y = MapEntry(a, b);
```

This breaks the caching mechanism of the code,
everything is recomputed.

You could implement a `Pair` with suitable `hashCode` and `equals`:

```
class Pair {
  final int first, second;

  Pair(this.first, this.second);

  bool operator==(Object other) =>
      other is Pair && first == other.first && second == other.second;

  int get hashCode => Object.hash(first, second);
}
```

Alternatively, you could compute a key to use with the cache,
given the range of inputs in the problem description:

```
class Solution {
  int findTargetSumWays(List<int> nums, int target) {
    Map<int, int> dp = {};
    int calculate(int i, int sum) {
      if (i == nums.length) {
        return sum == target ? 1 : 0;
      }

      final k = key(i, sum);
        
      return dp[k] ??
          (dp[k] = calculate(i + 1, sum + nums[i]) +
              calculate(i + 1, sum - nums[i]));
    }

    return calculate(0, 0);
  }
    
  int key(int index, int sum) {
      return sum * 1001 + index;
  }   
}
```

Using this key function saves the overhead of object creation.

#### Programming challenge sites are not benchmarking tools

These sites are not proper benchmarking tools,
and there are far too many unknowns an outsider simply cannot know:

- how efficiently are the program executors implemented for each language
- do the programs run on the same hardware
- do the programs run on the same network (same latency)

To name just a few.
Don't read too much meaning into the timing results on these sites.
They are just good enough to decide if your solution has the target time and space complexity.

#### Improve the Python code

There are many redundant parentheses:

> ```
> if(i == len(nums)):
>     return 1 if (total == target) else 0
>
> if((i, total) in dp):
>     return dp[(i, total)]
> ```

These could be:

```
if i == len(nums):
    return 1 if (total == target) else 0

if (i, total) in dp:
    return dp[i, total]
```

You can also take advantage that `False` is 0 in integer context,
and `True` is 1, simplifying the first conditional:

```
if i == len(nums):
    return total == target
```

Lastly, instead of using `dict` as the cache,
you can benefit from `@cache` in `functools` (implicitly imported on leetcode).

Putting it together:

```
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        @cache
        def calculate(i, total):
            if i == len(nums):
                return total == target
            
            return calculate(i+1, total + nums[i]) + calculate(i+1, total - nums[i])
        
        return calculate(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works ! Can you please explain why dart is taking longer than the python? Where exactly dart is lagging? Is it `map`?

Comment: Since I don't know how leetcode executes Python and Dart code, I cannot tell if one takes longer than the other and if so then why. I don't like to speculate when I cannot have the data. This is what I meant by the section to not treat programming challenge websites as benchmarking tools.